# Pairwise comparison with repitition

Tags: mean, multiple-comparisons, paired-comparisons

I did a test where I have 7 audio systems which where compared with each other and the tester have to say if the second one is better or worse than the first (scale -3 to 3). After comparing all 21 possibilities , they where repeated so I get two results for every pair.
Now my Problem is how I have to evaluate the data. My thoughts would be with a cross table like this:

```
        system1  system2 system3
system1    -         2       3
system2    -1         -      -1
system3    -2         0       -
```

Above the middle diagonal the results are inverted.
Is it right to calculate the mean over a line and the inverted mean for the row and then calculate the mean over these two for every system ?

Comment: What is it you want to know about these data? Do you want to know if the two ratings agree?

Comment: My final result should be the mean for every system to get a ranking